# VM: Can I detect that my virtualmachine is being paused?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Is there any signal or something that could allow me (guest OS) to recognize that my virtual machine is being paused in KVM/Qemu before it gets paused? It's important for me to not depend on option to enable communication between host<->guest in qemu.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to discover the paused state after the VM is unblocked, or during the paused state?

Comment: I need to know before it gets paused. After reasume I can detect it by clock I guess.

Comment: I strongly doubt you can be alerted *before* the machine is paused. Pausing it simple means the hypervisor put to sleeps its process and threads, with the vm not knowing anything about that by design.

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible.

Once the pause is triggered, there is no delay and no process to undo the pause before it is actually paused.

Not like the shutdown -h  in which you get a message that the system will shutdown soon.

Once your VM is paused, you can detect it because you can't use it anymore. It's as simple as that.

Comment: In qemu there is actually such thing: https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/GuestAgent

Comment: but I was wondering if I can use something like that, when the provider didnt enable the communication bridge between host and guest

Comment: You actually found the answer in that doc: 
`2) there is no way for a client to detect whether or not qemu-ga has
   [re-]connected or disconnected to the backend`

Comment: But the qemu-ga is returning a response, then shoiuld be aware? Anyway I was curious if there is any other signal or device behavior that could help detect this.

And that "client" is the hypervisor, so I guess it is unrelated?